# Need Help Identifying Sensor Connectory - 1996 Chevy G10

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, sensor, g10-van

I have a 96 Chevy G10/Express Van with a 5.0 V8. I noticed that there is a "dangling" connector, but am having trouble locating where it goes. It is located on the driver's side, and can be accessed both from underneath the hood and by removing the engine cover. Its reach extends to around the driver's side of the air breather (if pulled toward the front) or around the front of the left valve cover (around the PCV valve area). It is a roundish, two-wire connector.
[image]
I have been looking for where it plugs into, but have not been able find it. If I knew what the connector went to that would help immensely (instead of just blindly looking for any outlet). I suspected either the ECT or TPS but those their connectors seem to be attached (could be mistaken though as I am definitely not a mechanic).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what colors are the wires?

Comment: I believe one is solid green and the other is green with a white stripe. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly the A/C compressor high side switch on the back of the A/C compressor. Looks like a connector that would attach two harnesses.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I have not been able to verify it either way yet, but it is in the right area and was not something I really considered.